# What's the best way to use std::list container with std::map

Tags: c++

Is it valid to create a pointer to an std::list container in C++? The sample program seems to be working fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::list<int>*> map_list;

    std::list<int>* my_list = new std::list<int>;
    my_list->push_back(10);
    my_list->push_back(20);

    map_list.emplace(1, my_list);

    for (auto maplist : map_list)
    {
        std::cout<<"KEY:"<<maplist.first<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"std::list<int>* PTR:"<<maplist.second<<std::endl;

        auto mylist = *(maplist.second);
        for (auto x : mylist)
        {
            std::cout<<"Value:"<<x<<std::endl;
        }
    }

    /*resource release*/
    for (auto maplist : map_list)
    {
        std::cout<<"KEY:"<<maplist.first<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"std::list<int>* PTR:"<<maplist.second<<std::endl;

        maplist.second->clear();
        delete maplist.second;
    }
    map_list.clear();
    return 0;
}
```

I am wondering if this practice is advisable, or if there is anything wrong with the way I am creating a pointer to the std::list container.

Comment: The main drawback is that you need to manually delete the the lists.  There's also an extra apparently unnecessary indirection which has a (tiny) cost.  Why not just use `std::map<int, std::lint<int>>` instead?  It does not appear you actually need a pointer, so getting rid of it makes things simpler and more efficient.

Comment: You can 'new' almost anything, but why would you want to? Just make an instance in main, pass it by reference to functions that needed. Or you might even move it to another function or object. The whole idea in current C++ is that you should only allocate when it is really needed (look up "move semantics" online). Also see [R.11 C++ core coding guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-newdelete). (just give that document a look, it is interesting)

Comment: Summarizing, just use : `std::map<int, std::list<int>> map_list;` in this case it is totally fine. `std::list<int> my_list{1,2,3}; map_list.insert(key,std::move(my_list));` or even just `map_list.insert({key,{1,2,3}});`

Answer (score 3):

Using raw pointers is dangerous; makes it too easy to leak memory. `std::list` is pretty cheap to `move` though, so you could just skip the pointer and get the same basic behaviors with roughly equivalent performance (if anything, slightly *better* due to avoiding an extra layer of indirection):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::list<int>> map_list;  // No pointers!

    std::list<int> my_list;  // No new
    my_list.push_back(10);   // No pointers, so . over ->
    my_list.push_back(20);

    map_list.emplace(1, std::move(my_list));  // Move into map, avoid copy

    for (const auto& maplist : map_list)  // Iterate by reference, avoid copies; never modified, so const is good
    {
        std::cout<<"KEY:"<<maplist.first<<std::endl;

        const auto& mylist = maplist.second;  // Use reference to avoid copy
        for (auto x : mylist)  // It's just integers so references unnecessary here
        {
            std::cout<<"Value:"<<x<<std::endl;
        }
    }

    // No need for resource release at all; the `map` will clean its RAII managed contents automatically
    return 0;
}
```

Saves all the explicit code for cleanup, and uses move-semantics and references to avoid unnecessary copy work (admittedly pretty trivial in the program as written, with just one length 2 `list`, but copying many larger `list`s would be much more expensive than just referencing their contents, with no copies involved).